# Is there Standard Syntax for date/time addition/subtraction and variables?

Tags: .net, parsing, datetime, date-format

I am looking to add functionality to a web application to enable users to write a string representing date/time addition subtraction.  This needs to be server side, and in .NET.

Examples might be "`Today + 2w`", "`FirstOfCurrentMonth - 1M`", "`Now + 2h`" etc.

This would have a few standard variables, such as:

- Today (today's date)
- Now (today's date and time)
- FirstOfCurrentMonth
- LastOfCurrentMonth
- FirstOfCurrentYear
- LastOfCurrentYear

and enable arithmetic for:

- seconds
- minutes
- hours
- days
- weeks
- months
- years

This is obviously not a large project to write, but my questions are:

- Is there any standard syntax, at least for the date arithmetic part?
- Are there any tools written in .NET (or maybe others) that could be used for this?

Comment: Check out the .NET documentation for [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx), [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx), and the associated `Parse` and `ParseExact` methods.

Comment: i have used these, and prefer NodaTime.  I was looking for something that parses text values e.g. "+2w", rather than translating that to Today().AddDays(x)

Comment: So this is a tool request? *[sigh]*

Comment: Either an existing tool, or just standardised syntax that I could base a new tool on...

Comment: You're basically describing a small [DSL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx).  I don't know of one.

Comment: Where are you supposed to ask such advice then?  Stack Overflow users would be better placed to answer this than anyone else...

Comment: Sounds like "interpreter" pattern to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question, no there isn't a standard for tokens like "now", "today", "yesterday", or "first of current month", etc.  At least not that I am aware of.

For the second part, *yes*, there is a standard for tokens that define durations of time in discrete segments.  This is the second (often overlooked) part of ISO8601.  You can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

For example, `P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S` represents a duration of "three years, six months, four days, twelve hours, thirty minutes, and five seconds".

[Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) is one library in .Net that has support for ISO8601 durations (called a `Period` in Noda Time).  You can use [NodaTime.Text.PeriodPattern](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg/docs/api/Index.html?topic=html/T_NodaTime_Text_PeriodPattern.htm) to work with them.

Noda Time might be a good basis for the rest of your concerns as well. The text pieces are extensible, so perhaps you could write a custom pattern formatter and parser to work with your own tokens.

Just to give you a taste of how this might work, consider the following example:

```cs
var pattern = PeriodPattern.NormalizingIsoPattern;
var result = pattern.Parse("P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S");
if (!result.Success) return;  // or throw, or whatever

var period = result.Value;
Debug.WriteLine("Years: {0}", period.Years);
Debug.WriteLine("Months: {0}", period.Months);
Debug.WriteLine("Days: {0}", period.Days);
Debug.WriteLine("Hours: {0}", period.Hours);
Debug.WriteLine("Minutes: {0}", period.Minutes);
Debug.WriteLine("Seconds: {0}", period.Seconds);

var now = SystemClock.Instance.Now;
var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/New_York"];
var localNow = now.InZone(zone).LocalDateTime;
var output = localNow + period;

Debug.WriteLine(localNow);
Debug.WriteLine(output);
```

Output:

```
Years: 3
Months: 6
Days: 4
Hours: 12
Minutes: 30
Seconds: 5
7/11/2013 12:03:58 AM
1/15/2017 12:34:03 PM
```

Comment: This is great, many thanks for pointing me in the direction of the ISO standard, had no idea that existed.  Also as I am already using Nodatime, the implementation will be very straightforward.